Kiosk mode Android using custom DPC
I have written a custom DPC app that acts as a kiosk for an Android device. I am trying to understand the different ways to set this app as device owner. I know of the way over ADB, but this seems to be designed for testing. The standard way seems to be to set it at device setup with a QR code. Does the QR code way require the phone to be tied to an enterprise with Android management API? I have no need to remotely manage the device, I just want to find the best way to set the DPC app as the device owner.

Does this answer your question? Does Android management API support custom DPC apps?
